# How to know when npm `unzip` module has finished unzipping file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, zip

I'm using the `unzip` module from npm to extract the contents of a zip archive.  I need to know when it is done extracting and the file has been completely written to disk.

#### My code:

```
fs.createReadStream('master.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'gitdownloads/repo' }));
```

#### What I've tried:

My first thought was that I could tap into the stream and listen for the finish event, but `unzip` only takes input: it doesn't return another stream.

I also looked to see if the `unzip` module had a "finish" callback.  No luck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the github [README](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip)

> Extract emits the 'close' event once the zip's contents have been
>   fully extracted to disk.

You'll want to do something like:

```
fs.createReadStream('master.zip')
  .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'gitdownloads/repo' }))
   .on('close', function () {
     ...
   });
```