# node.js convert xml to json

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to convert xml compressed zip file to json file.

I used these.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/unzip
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2json

```
'use strict';

let fs = require('fs')
let unzip = require('unzip')
let parser = require('xml2json');

let originalFilePath = process.argv[2];

let XMLFileName = originalFilePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace('.zip', '')
let XMLFileDirectory = '/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/' + XMLFileName + '/'
let XMLFilePath = '/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/' + XMLFileName + '/doc.xml'

let jsonFilePath = '/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/' + XMLFileName + '/doc.json'

convertToXML(originalFilePath).then(() => { createJson(jsonData) })

function convertToXML(filePath) {
    return new Promise(() => {
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: XMLFileDirectory }))
    })
}

function createJson(jsonData) {
    fs.writeFile(jsonFilePath, JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, '    '))
}
```

I got error.

> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Please help me.

convertToXML and createJson is properly.
But I have to use promise , since I have to run createJson after xml file was created.
But I am  having trouble using promise.

---

Sorry I forgot to write these

```
let XMLFileData = fs.readFileSync(XMLFilePath, 'utf-8')
let jsonData = parser.toJson(XMLFileData)
```

Now my code is like this.

```
'use strict';

let fs = require('fs')
let unzip = require('unzip')
let parser = require('xml2json');

let originalFilePath = process.argv[2];

let XMLFileName = originalFilePath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '').replace('.zip', '')
let XMLFileDirectory = '/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/' + XMLFileName + '/'
let XMLFilePath = '/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/' + XMLFileName + '/doc.xml'

let jsonFilePath = '/users/*****/desktop/templatexml/' + XMLFileName + '/doc.json'

convertToXML(originalFilePath).then(() => {

    let XMLFileData = fs.readFileSync(XMLFilePath, 'utf-8')
    let jsonData = parser.toJson(XMLFileData)

    createJson(jsonData)

})

function convertToXML(filePath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: XMLFileDirectory }))
    })
}

function createJson(jsonData) {
    fs.writeFile(jsonFilePath, JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, '    '))
}
```

doc.xml would be created but doc.json won't be created.

---

Thank you so much I did like this.
But I got an error.

> DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback
>   is deprecated.

```
convertToXML(originalFilePath)

function convertToXML(filePath) {
    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(unzip.Extract({
        path: XMLFileDirectory
    })).on('close', function() {
        createJson()
    });
 }

function createJson() {
   let XMLFileData = fs.readFileSync(XMLFilePath, 'utf-8')
   let jsonData = parser.toJson(XMLFileData)
   fs.writeFile(jsonFilePath, JSON.stringify(jsonData, null, '    '))
}
```

I think this error happens because there is no xmlfile.
I still can't run createJson() after xmlFile is created.

---

Now I made correct code.

I had to change

"fs.writeFile"

to

"fs.writeFileSync"

Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change this line ***new Promise***

From:

```
return new Promise(() => {
}
```

To:

```
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(unzip.Extract({
        path: XMLFileDirectory
    })).on('close', function () {
        resolve();
    });
})
```

**Updated**:

From the github [README](https://github.com/EvanOxfeld/node-unzip)

> Extract emits the 'close' event once the zip's contents have been
>   fully extracted to disk.

More detail about unzip at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35654811/how-to-know-when-npm-unzip-module-has-finished-unzipping-file)